# Get date range between two dates excluding weekends

Tags: php, arrays, date

Given the following dates:

```
6/30/2010 - 7/6/2010
```

and a static variable:

```
$h = 7.5
```

I need to create an array like:

```
Array ( [2010-06-30] => 7.5 [2010-07-01] => 7.5 => [2010-07-02] => 7.5 => [2010-07-05] => 7.5 => [2010-07-06] => 7.5)
```

Weekend days excluded.

No, it's not homework...for some reason I just can't think straight today.

Comment: Enumerate the dates, using `getdate(iter_date)["wday"]` to skip the week-end (wday: 0, or 6).

Answer (score 28, accepted):

For PHP >= 5.3.0, use the [DatePeriod](http://www.php.net/dateperiod) class. It's unfortunately barely documented.

```
$start = new DateTime('6/30/2010');
$end = new DateTime('7/6/2010');
$oneday = new DateInterval("P1D");

$days = array();
$data = "7.5";

/* Iterate from $start up to $end+1 day, one day in each iteration.
   We add one day to the $end date, because the DatePeriod only iterates up to,
   not including, the end date. */
foreach(new DatePeriod($start, $oneday, $end->add($oneday)) as $day) {
    $day_num = $day->format("N"); /* 'N' number days 1 (mon) to 7 (sun) */
    if($day_num < 6) { /* weekday */
        $days[$day->format("Y-m-d")] = $data;
    } 
}    
print_r($days);
```

Comment: When I run this I get 

Array ( [2010-06-30] => 7.5 [2010-07-01] => 7.5 [2010-07-02] => 7.5 [2010-07-05] => 7.5 ) 

It's missing the last day, 7/6.

Am I missing something simple?

Comment: Seems like changing 
$end = '7/6/2010'; 
to 
$end = date ( 'm/d/Y' , strtotime ( '+1 day' , strtotime ('7/06/2010') )  );
Gets me what I'm looking for.

Comment: Yes, the DatePeriod appearently stops _before_ the end-date. My bad, fixed.

Comment: If we dont now the end date, how to get date range for n days excluding weekends.

Answer (score 5):

The simplest method:

```
$start = strtotime('6/30/2010');
$end = strtotime('7/6/2010');
$result = array();
while ($start <= $end) {
    if (date('N', $start) <= 5) {
        $current = date('m/d/Y', $start);
        $result[$current] = 7.5;
    }
    $start += 86400;
}
print_r($result);
```

**UPDATE:**  Forgot to skip weekends.  This should work now.

Comment: Watch out for daylight savings

Comment: Good answer, for place without daylight saving :)

Answer (score 1):

This is gnud's answer but as a function (also added an option to exclude the current day from the calculation):

(examples below)

```
public function getNumberOfDays($startDate, $endDate, $hoursPerDay="7.5", $excludeToday=true)
{
    // d/m/Y
    $start = new DateTime($startDate);
    $end = new DateTime($endDate);
    $oneday = new DateInterval("P1D");

    $days = array();

    /* Iterate from $start up to $end+1 day, one day in each iteration.
    We add one day to the $end date, because the DatePeriod only iterates up to,
    not including, the end date. */
    foreach(new DatePeriod($start, $oneday, $end->add($oneday)) as $day) {
        $day_num = $day->format("N"); /* 'N' number days 1 (mon) to 7 (sun) */
        if($day_num < 6) { /* weekday */
            $days[$day->format("Y-m-d")] = $hoursPerDay;
        } 
    }    

    if ($excludeToday)
        array_pop ($days);

    return $days;       
}
```

And to use it:

```
$date1 = "2012-01-12";
$date2 = date('Y-m-d'); //today's date  

$daysArray = getNumberOfDays($date1, $date2);

echo 'hours: ' . array_sum($daysArray);
echo 'days: ' . count($daysArray);
```

Comment: hello @jarrod, I want minutes toooo.

Answer (score 0):

This is OOP approach, just in case. It returns an array with all of dates, except the weekends days.

```
    class Date{
        public function getIntervalBetweenTwoDates($startDate, $endDate){
            $period = new DatePeriod(
                 new DateTime($startDate),
                 new DateInterval('P1D'),
                 new DateTime($endDate)
            );
            $all_days = array();$i = 0;
            foreach($period as $date) {
                if ($this->isWeekend($date->format('Y-m-d'))){
                    $all_days[$i] = $date->format('Y-m-d');
                    $i++;
                }
            }
            return $all_days;
        }
        public function isWeekend($date) {
            $weekDay = date('w', strtotime($date));
            if (($weekDay == 0 || $weekDay == 6)){
                return false;
            }else{
                return true;
            }
        }
    }
    $d = new Date();
    var_dump($d->getIntervalBetweenTwoDates('2015-08-01','2015-08-08'));
```

Comment: What if you have two same dates?
var_dump($d->getIntervalBetweenTwoDates('2015-08-01','2015-08-01'))