# PHP: Add days except Sunday

Tags: php

I need to add days in the given date but i need to exclude Sunday.

Here is my code which is working fine but i am not able to exclude the Sunday.

```
    $service_start_date = new DateTime('2020-10-18');
    $service_end_date = new DateTime('2020-10-25');
//echo $service_start_date;
   $daterange = new DatePeriod($service_start_date, new DateInterval('P1D'), $service_end_date);
       foreach($daterange as $date){
         $service_date = $date->format("Y-m-d");
         echo $service_date;
    }
```

Comment: It doesn't look like you try to exclude Sundays

Comment: Thanks for the comment john. This is just a sample date. Actual date may come from database. I have seen the option to exclude the weekends but i only need to exclude Sunday.

Comment: That really doesn't matter. In your loop check if a day is Sunday. If so, skip it.

Comment: Wow. Thats a great idea. I didn't thought about it. Thanks

Comment: [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21085285/how-can-i-exclude-saturday-and-sunday-when-i-generate-dates) might help...

Comment: How can i close this question? I can't delete it as there is an answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use the DatePeriod class. There's a related question explaining how to do the same, except he/she is excluding the entire weekend: [Get date range between two dates excluding weekends](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3352712/get-date-range-between-two-dates-excluding-weekends)

You can also loop through you're dates and check for Sundays to exclude them, like suggested in the comments (to make this answer complete).

Comment: Maybe this should just have been a close vote with that linked as a duplicate. As you point out, the accepted answer with a single number change will do what OP wants.

Comment: @Jonnix I agree, but I don't think I can mark posts as duplicate with my reputation so I had to do it this way for as far as I know. :)

Comment: I can't remember what rep you need to do that, but reason seems fair.

Comment: To flag a duplicate, just leave a comment and someone else may do the closing for you.