# Get Dropdown List Between Two Date Range Excluding Weekends In Php

Tags: php, date, date-range

I am developing a dynamic website where the website backend admin will select two dates (From - To) and the user in the front-end will be able to get a dropdown list between those two dates excluding weekends along with the name of the day (For e.g: `<option>27th April 2015 - Monday</option>`)

I tried going by this link but in vain:
[Link to get date range between two dates excluding weekends.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3352712/get-date-range-between-two-dates-excluding-weekends)

Please Help.

The table row name for first date is `skype_date_start` and for the second date is `skype_date_end`.

My code as follows:

```
`$start = '2013/01/01'; //start date
$end = '2013/01/30'; //end date

$dates = array();
$start = $current = strtotime($start);
$end = strtotime($end);

while ($current <= $end) {
    $dates[] = date('Y/m/d', $current);
    $current = strtotime('+1 days', $current);
}

//now $dates hold an array of all the dates within that date range
print_r($dates);`
```

This only prints the array in a cluster form like :
`Array ( [0] => 2013/01/01 [1] => 2013/01/02 [2] => 2013/01/03 [3] => 2013/01/04 [4] => 2013/01/05 [5] => 2013/01/06 [6] => 2013/01/07 [7] => 2013/01/08 [8] => 2013/01/09 [9] => 2013/01/10 [10] => 2013/01/11 [11] => 2013/01/12 [12] => 2013/01/13 [13] => 2013/01/14 [14] => 2013/01/15 [15] => 2013/01/16 [16] => 2013/01/17 [17] => 2013/01/18 [18] => 2013/01/19 [19] => 2013/01/20 [20] => 2013/01/21 [21] => 2013/01/22 [22] => 2013/01/23 [23] => 2013/01/24 [24] => 2013/01/25 [25] => 2013/01/26 [26] => 2013/01/27 [27] => 2013/01/28 [28] => 2013/01/29 [29] => 2013/01/30 )`.

I cannot exclude the weekends and also cannot get it to be printed as `<option>27th April, 2015 - Monday</option><option>28th April 2015 - Tuesday</option>` & so on... to the last date.

Comment: I Guess This Question Is Too Tough To Be Answered !!

Comment: Well, for a start, there's no actual question here. For another, there's also no code. Could you add your current code to the question? What is the problem you're having with it? Why doesn't it work? What doesn't it do that it's supposed to?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are almost there. Before adding a date to `dates` array you need to check if its  a week day or not. If it is then add it otherwise skip that date and continue to next iteration. Like this:

```
<?php
    $start = '2013/01/01'; //start date
    $end = '2013/01/30'; //end date

    $currentDate = strtotime($start);
    $endDate = strtotime($end);
    $dates = array();

    while ($currentDate <= $endDate ) {
        if(!isWeekend($currentDate)){
            $dates[] = date('Y/m/d', $currentDate );
        }

        $currentDate = strtotime('+1 days', $currentDate );
    }

    function isWeekend($date) {
        return date('w', $date) == 0 || date('w', $date) == 6;
    }
?>
```

Next you need to create your `select` tag like this:

```
<select name=date_range=>
    <?php
         for($i = 0; $i < count($dates); $i++) {
              echo "<option value='{$dates[$i]}'>";
              echo date("Y/m/d - l", strtotime($dates[$i]));
              echo "</option>";
         }
    ?>
</select>
```

Comment: i am a very new comer in php. Can you do me a favor to write down the total complete code including the weekend functions ? It would be of great help.

Comment: `weekend` function is already there. Look at my answer. Also i've provided you with code for building `select` element too. So what more do you need.

Comment: It says the follow - `Missing argument 1 for isWeekend()`

Comment: That's what it is showing: `<select name=date_range=>
    <option value='2013/01/01'>1970/01/01 - Thursday</option><option value='2013/01/02'>1970/01/01 - Thursday</option><option value='2013/01/03'>1970/01/01 - Thursday</option><option value='2013/01/23'>1970/01/01 - Thursday</option></select>
`
I have deleted some options as it was not fitting in here. But all the options were same.

Comment: i forgot to convert data to timestamp before outputting in `option` tag. It's fixed now.

Comment: Also, the dates in the option values which seem to work are not filtering the weekends.

Comment: This is fetching the dates with the days as expected but it is not skipping the weekends as expected.

Answer (score 0):

For the Date Formatting use this:

`$dates[] = date('j F, Y - D', $current);`

instead of

`$dates[] = date('Y/m/d', $current);`

for skipping weekends: (Ref: https://stackoverflow.com/a/4802362/1741052)

use a function to determine the current date if its a weekend or not

```
function isWeekend($date) {
$weekDay = date('w', strtotime($date));
return ($weekDay == 0 || $weekDay == 6);
}
```

Try the below..
Code Example:

```
$start = '2013/01/01'; //start date
$end = '2013/01/31'; //end date

$dates = array();
$start = $current = strtotime($start);
$end = strtotime($end);

while ($current <= $end) 
{
    $weekDay = date('w', $current); 
    print(" <br/> Week Day: {$weekDay}");
    if($weekDay != 0 && $weekDay != 6)
    {
        // Not a Weekend
        $dates[] = date('j F, Y - D', $current);    
        $current = strtotime('+1 days', $current);
    }
}

//now $dates hold an array of all the dates within that date range
print_r($dates);
```